# Настроить скролл

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня есть такие элементы

```
    {item.regions.map((item) => (
            <Box>
                <Typography
                    color={selectedChip === item.region_name ? 'green' : theme.palette?.text?.disabled}
                    typography='overline'
                    sx={{ ml: 2 }}
                >
                    {item.region_name.toUpperCase()}
                </Typography>
                <Typography
                    ref={targetRef}
                    typography='sequence'
                    sx={{
                        borderTop: `1px solid ${
                            selectedChip === item.region_name ? 'green' : theme.palette?.text?.disabled
                        }`,
                        letterSpacing: '4px',
                        fontSize: '14px',
                        display: 'flex',
                        ml: 2,
                        pb: 1,
                        flexWrap: 'nowrap',
                        whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
                    }}
                >
                    {item.sequence}
                </Typography>
            </Box>
        ))}
```

я перебираю в map-е массив объектов названия этих объектов распологаются сверху, а ниже распологаются последовательности - (некоторая последовательность букв). Последовательности длиннее чем названия и соответственно я не вижу все последовательности, у меня есть скролл и я их могу прокрутить. Хочется сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на название, например 3-го объекта, скролл с последовательностями прокручивался до 3-ей последовательности.
Вот что я сделал

```
const targetRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);



  <Typography
                    ref={targetRef}
                    typography='sequence'
```

и дальше на onClick чипа (Chip mui) с названиями я повесил такую логику

```
targetRef.current?.scrollIntoView();
```

но скролл прокручивается только до конца последовательностей, а не до нужного, это и логично я никак не помечаю до какого мне нужно, возможно нужно использовать scrollBy() , но как получить нужный мне элемент не знаю
Дело в том, что этот тег

```
  <Typography
                    ref={targetRef}
                    typography='sequence'
```

генерится в map-е и мне нужно навешивать реф на конкретный элемент из map-а, то есть есть имя name1 и есть  последовательность sequence1, также есть name2 и sequence2 и таких штук 20, так при нажатии на name14, скролл должен сам передвигаться к sequence14. Может какие-нибудь идеи подкините или видео какое-нибудь, а то я как-то даже загуглить это не знаю как